# Unable to add chrome-extension "url" to firebase whitelisted domains

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

I've been loosely following the boilerplate in [quickstart-js](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/chromextension). I don't want to rely on Chrome's identify provider but rather want users to be able to sign in to my extension with their Google login using a popup so I haven't gone through the song and dance of requesting identity permissions in my `manifest.json`. My file is as follows:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Firebase Auth in Chrome Extension Sample",
  "description": "This sample shows how to authorize Firebase in a Chrome extension using a Google account.",
  "version": "2.1",
  "icons": {
    "128": "firebase.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "firebase.png",
    "default_popup": "credentials.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

I have baseline code that is similar to what's in quickstart-js. The relevant portion in my `credentials.js` is here:

```js
/**
 * Start the auth flow and authorizes to Firebase.
 */
async function startAuth() {
  await firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  const res = await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
}

// Starts the sign-in process.
function startSignIn() {
  document.getElementById('quickstart-button').disabled = true;
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  } else {
    startAuth();
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  initApp();
};
```

This seems like it should work but constantly receive the following message:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: This chrome extension ID (chrome-extension://cckmbfklaloiadcphibealkhpncehpng) is not authorized to run this operation. Add it to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.

[According to the official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#authenticate_with_firebase_in_a_chrome_extension), I should be able to whitelist my Chrome extension's ID in the Firebase control panel. I'm repeatedly given a success message but the extension "url" doesn't show up in my list of Authorized Domains and I keep getting the error message.

Is there somewhere else I need to add the Chrome Extension url?

[image]

Comment: This is a Firebase bug. Please file a support ticket at https://firebase.google.com/support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have just been a regression. I reached out to Firebase support, got an answer a few days later, but by that point the bug was fixed.